# Why does discord.py bot sends multiple messages if there is a break out of loop?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, python-3.10

My discord.py bot is meant to send notifications in "streamers" text channel when a streamer from SQLite3 DB assigned to this particular server goes live. The problem is that bot sends multiple notification messages (actually exactly equal to channel.history limit) when there is a break out of the loop. What may cause this problem?
P/S: don't mind me for these > 79 lines of code, they are going to get fixed when I'm done with the logic.

```py
def _checkuser(user: str) -> dict | None:
    """Запрос к Twitch с проверкой, стримит ли указанный пользователь."""
    stream = requests.get(
        'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=' + user,
        headers=TWITCH_HEADERS,
    )
    stream_data = stream.json()
    if len(stream_data['data']) == 1:
        return stream_data['data'][0]
    else:
        return None


@bot.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    """Обработчик события при запуске бота."""
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def live_notification_loop() -> None:
        """Луп проверки стримеров."""
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            cursor.execute(
                f'SELECT id, name FROM streamers WHERE server_id = {guild.id}'
            )
            streamers = cursor.fetchmany()
            if streamers is not None:
                channel: discord.TextChannel = discord.utils.get(
                    guild.channels,
                    name='streamers',
                )
                for user_id, name in streamers:
                    status = _checkuser(name)
                    user = bot.get_user(user_id)
                    if status:
                        # messages = await channel.history(limit=200).flatten()
                        # for message in messages:
                        async for message in channel.history(limit=10):
                            if str(user.mention) in message.content:
                                break
                            else:
                                ALERT_MSG = '{streamer} запустил трансляцию. Не пропустите!'
                                ALERT_EMBED = discord.Embed(
                                    title=EMBED_TITLE,
                                    description=f'{status["user_name"]} играет в {status["game_name"]} для {status["viewer_count"]} зрителей.',
                                    url=f'https://twitch.tv/{status["user_name"]}',
                                    colour=0x6441A5,
                                    timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                                )
                                ALERT_EMBED.set_author(
                                    name=f'{status["user_name"]} запустил трансляцию на Twitch.',
                                    url=f'https://twitch.tv/{status["user_name"]}'
                                )
                                ALERT_EMBED.set_image(
                                    url=status["thumbnail_url"].format(
                                        width=640,
                                        height=360,
                                    )
                                )
                                await channel.send(
                                    ALERT_MSG.format(
                                        streamer=user.mention
                                    ),
                                    embed=ALERT_EMBED,
                                )
    live_notification_loop.start()
```

Comment: i think it's the indentation problem with live_notification_loop.start() place that above bot token and bot.run command and try

Comment: @majinvejetho that wouldn't work: it's a async loop task launched on on_ready event. But I discovered that it sends as much notifications in the channel as there were messages after last notification. Very weird. I don't really see problem in logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added break after await.send, one notification message now.